# How to hide the j session id

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, cookies, session-cookies, jsessionid

When I authenticate my application and by pressing F12 if I open Network at cookies section I can see the J SESSION ID in plain text.
How to encrypt or hide it?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBPU.jpg]

Comment: This is normal behavior. Why exactly does that form a problem to you?

Comment: i need that JSESSIONID to mask so that it is not visible.as it may lead to security related issues

Comment: That's it always when someone exposes its own session cookies into public for some unclear reason. You can't do anything against it. This is not specific to JSESSIONID. Other languages like PHP and ASP also have exactly this "problem".

Comment: Use HTTPS to secure your site!

Comment: @fantarama: HTTPS doesn't protect against ignorant people who share their session cookies by means of e.g. screenshots, account sharing, or XSS holes in the website itself. It only protects against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: will HTTP ONLY flag help me? <session-config>
 <cookie-config>
  <http-only>true</http-only>
 </cookie-config>
</session-config>

Comment: HttpOnly means that the cookie is only transmitted as a part of a HTTP request. It can't be accessed by JavaScript. You should set this flag on cookies. What security related issues are you trying to protect by hiding the cookie?

Comment: i want to hide the JSESSIONID (by masking or encrypting or protecting from accessing it) as even in client browser i dont want to see the session id is thier any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Its important to hide session ID for MITMA but of accessibility you need it to let web sites know who you are and what was your last activity. The technique which is widely used is limited time session ID

Answer (score 0):

What would be the benefit of encrypting or masking it? Assuming there were an uncomplicated and non-timewasting way to do this, an attacker only need copy the encrypted form of the token and feed it to your application and your application will dutifully decrypt it, regardless of the source. Ditto for masking it: whatever masking you perform before transporting it, means that some component on the server side will need to unmask it to make it usable. So really, you're not going to achieve anything in the direction you're looking at.

The major viable threat here is a session-replay attack, which can easily be mitigated by ensuring that

1. Your sessions don't live for too long
2. You implement a single active session policy, where any given user id cannot have more than one active session - meaning that even if a session ID were compromised, no new session can be started with the stolen token.

If you're that concerned with the handling of session tokens, you should read through [OWASP's session management article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management) that will give you better practice in protecting your sessions; what you're looking at now is just distracting